# promise is pending but the code is working properly

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, promise

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql');


const pool = mysql.createPool({
  socketPath:'',
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'fatima',
  password: 'acess',
  database: 'acess',
  multipleStatements: true,
  canRetry: true,
  connectionLimit : 1000,
  connectTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
  acquireTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
  timeout         : 60 * 60 * 1000,
  port: 3000
});

 
let db = {};

db.getUserByEmail = (email) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], (error, users)=>{
            if(error){
                return reject(error);
            }
            return resolve(users[0]);
        });
    });
};
 
 

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  
  try{ 
    const email = "sami@mail.com";
    // const password = req.body.Pass;
    const user = await db.getUserByEmail(email);
    console.log("hi",user); } 
    } catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

})
```

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node main.js`
listening on port 3000
Database Connected
hi Promise { <pending> }
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node main.js`
listening on port 3000
Database Connected
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node main.js`
listening on port 3000
Database Connected
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node main.js`
listening on port 3000
Database Connected
```

My login route is not workoing properly dirst when i executeed my program without async function it showed promise pending but when i used async function my program was kept on executing and it did not console.log anything.

i hope this explaination works in understanding the problem. i have given the required code above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the `db.getUserByEmail()` function, try removing the `return` statement with `reject` and `resolve`.

Comment: No still not working

Comment: router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  
  try{ 
    const email = "sami@mail.com";
    // const password = req.body.Pass;
    const user = await db.getUserByEmail(email);
    console.log("hi",user);
    res.send("Logged in successfully!");
  } catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).send("An error occurred while logging in.");
  }

})

Comment: Try replacing router with above code.

Comment: NO did not work for me

Comment: it did not show anything on console

Comment: Check that the promise is actually resolving. You can add a .then() function to the promise to log the resolved value.

Comment: router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const email = "sami@mail.com";
    // const password = req.body.Pass;
    db.getUserByEmail(email)
        .then(user => {
            console.log("hi",user);
            res.send(user);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            res.send(error);
        });
});

Comment: I tried adding .then but still nothing happened